# Калькулятор Kivy: как запретить ввод одинаковых знаков (+,-,*) подряд: 4++3

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Есть код на Kivy:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.label import Label

Config.set('graphics','resizable','0')
Config.set('graphics','width','400')
Config.set('graphics','height','450')


class Calculator(App):
    def calculat_e(self,instance):
        self.lbl.text = str(eval(self.lbl.text))
        self.formula = ''

    def update_label(self):
            if self.formula != '+' and self.formula != '*' and self.formula != '-' and self.formula != '.' :
                # if '*' in mas:    
                self.lbl.text  = self.formula

    def add_number(self,instance):
        if self.formula == '0' :
            self.formula = ''
        if self.formula == '+':
            self.formula = ''
        if self.formula == '-':
            self.formula = ''
        if self.formula == '*':
            self.formula = ''
        if self.formula == '.':
            self.formula = ''
        # if self.lbl.text[len(self.lbl.text)-1] != '**':
        if len(self.lbl.text) != 13:
            self.formula += str(instance.text)
            self.update_label()

    def clear_(self,instance):
        self.lbl.text = '0'
        self.formula = ''

    def build(self):

        self.formula = "0"

        bl = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        gl = GridLayout(cols=4,spacing=3,padding=[10])
        self.lbl = (Label(text='0',font_size= 50,size_hint=[1,.35],text_size=(400-20,450 * .35 -20 ),halign='right',valign='center'))
        bl.add_widget(self.lbl)
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='7',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='8',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='9',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='*',background_color=[0,0,1,1],on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='4',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='5',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='6',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='-',background_color=[0,0,1,1],on_press= self.add_number))

        gl.add_widget(Button(text='1',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='2',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='3',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='+',background_color=[0,0,1,1],on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='C',on_press=self.clear_,background_color=[0,1,1,1]))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='0',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='.',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='=',background_color=[0,0,1,1],on_press = self.calculat_e))

        bl.add_widget(gl)
        return bl

Calculator().run()
```

Это мой первый калькулятор на Kivy.Но никак не могу придумать как запретить ввод одинаковых знаков (+,-,*), т.е,чтобы не было 4+++++++4 или 3..............5,уже 2 день мучаюсь,подскажите кто знает.Желательно не меняя этот код - просто добавляя новый

Используется Python 3.5

Answer (score -1):

```
def __init__(self):
    self.formula = ''
    self.items = ['*', '-', '+', '.']

def add_number(self, instance):
    if self.formula in self.items:
        return
```

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста,объяснение

Comment: Куда это нужно добавить?

Answer (score -2):

Вместо этого:

```
if len(self.lbl.text) != 13:
  self.formula += str(instance.text)
  self.update_label()
```

Вставьте это:

```
char = str(instance.text) # Вы уверены, что нужно приводить к строке?

if char in '+-*\.':
  if char != self.formula[-1]:
    self.formula += char
    self.update_label()
else:  
  self.formula += char
  self.update_label()
```

Comment: куда это нужно вставить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, потрудитесь найти похожее место в вашем коде.

Comment: Уже потрудился, и повсталял куда можно и куда нельзя,но все равно не могу найти.

Comment: @QqqqSsss обновил ответ.